# How to Implement a text field for Filtering the elements in the Combo-viewer

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Is it possible to add a text field to JFace combo-viewer so that the elements can be filtered out by keyboard input like `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really add anything to the `ComboViewer` but you can do this using a separate `Text` field.

Add a `ViewerFilter` to the `ComboViewer` using the `addFilter` method. This filter should use the current value of the `Text` field to filter the combo contents.

Add a `ModifyListener` to the `Text` field which will be notified each time the text is changed. In the listener you can refresh the combo viewer so that the viewer filter is run again.

Comment: Thanks for your response Greg. I have some queries for you..

In eclipse, the Editor area will have a symbol ">>" (ShowList) which is used to show the list of opened files. The user can get focus of the required file from the list either by selecting the file or type & searching (filtering) the file, when the number of opened files are more. 

I need such a same behavior in my multi-page editor in which the file contents are populated. So that I can toggle between multiple files without creating new editor for every file.

Comment: That is a new question. Accept this answer and ask a new question with more detail.